# Restkit - [RKManagedObjectRequestOperation deleteTargetObject:] not called

Tags: ios, restkit, http-delete

I am using the following to delete objects using RestKit (0.23.1):

```
[self.objectManager deleteObject:myObject path:path parameters:nil success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSLog(@"success deleting myObject");
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"failure deleting myObject");
}];
```

This does create the correct DELETE request and the server returns a 200 status code. However, the local data is not deleted from Core Data. If I do a fetch for the deleted object after the success block above is fired, the fetch returns the object that should be deleted.

[The documentation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKManagedObjectRequestOperation.html#overview) reads:

> RKManagedObjectRequestOperation adds special behavior to DELETE
>   requests. Upon retrieving a successful (2xx status code) response for
>   a DELETE, the operation will invoke deleteObject: with the operations
>   targetObject on the managed object context. This will delete the
>   target object from the local store in conjunction the successfully
>   deleted remote representation.

Doing a little spelunking it looks like `-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation deleteTargetObject:]` is not being called. It seems that it should be called by `-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation willFinish]`.

It seems like there may be a logic error in the gating if statement in `-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation willFinish]`.

```
- (void)willFinish
{
    NSMutableIndexSet *deleteableStatusCodes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    [deleteableStatusCodes addIndex:404]; // Not Found
    [deleteableStatusCodes addIndex:410]; // Gone
    if (self.error && self.targetObjectID
        && [[[self.HTTPRequestOperation.request HTTPMethod] uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@"DELETE"]
        && [deleteableStatusCodes containsIndex:self.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (! [self deleteTargetObject:&error]) {
            RKLogWarning(@"Secondary error encountered while attempting to delete target object in response to 404 (Not Found) or 410 (Gone) status code: %@", error);
            self.error = error;
        } else {
            if (! [self saveContext:&error]) {

            } else {
                // All good, clear any errors
                self.error = nil;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems like `-[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation willFinish]` should be as follows:

```
- (void)willFinish
{
    NSMutableIndexSet *deleteableStatusCodes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    [deleteableStatusCodes addIndex:404]; // Not Found
    [deleteableStatusCodes addIndex:410]; // Gone
    [deleteableStatusCodes addIndexes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
    if (self.error == nil
        && self.targetObjectID
        && [[[self.HTTPRequestOperation.request HTTPMethod] uppercaseString] isEqualToString:@"DELETE"]
        && [deleteableStatusCodes containsIndex:self.HTTPRequestOperation.response.statusCode]) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if (! [self deleteTargetObject:&error]) {
            RKLogWarning(@"Secondary error encountered while attempting to delete target object in response to 404 (Not Found) or 410 (Gone) status code: %@", error);
            self.error = error;
        } else {
            if (! [self saveContext:&error]) {

            } else {
                // All good, clear any errors
                self.error = nil;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize the changes, I added the successful status codes to the `deleteableStatusCodes` index set and check to make sure that `self.error` is equal to nil.

Is my logic change sound, or am I misunderstanding some RestKit convention here? It seems like my logic change aligns with the quoted statement from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking in the wrong place. See the line:

```
success = [weakSelf deleteTargetObject:&error];
```

In the `performMappingOnResponseWithCompletionBlock:` method in `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` which checks for success status and deletes the object.

The code you have edited is to deal with error responses which, in a nice REST interface, mean the same thing as a DELETE success response.

Comment: You are correct, I was looking in the wrong location. This is working as expected.